# How to determine System Environment Variables with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs

When developing client-side applications in the past I have always used some sort of server-side application to package and serve the JavaScript.  This allowed me to pass environment variables through to the client that varied between production and development environments.

I'm working on a pure client-side application using RequireJS and serving it with a static web server.  Some configuration varies depending on whether the app is being run locally in development or in production (i.e. the URL of the server to which it will make AJAX requests).

What's the best way to determine the current environment with RequireJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// you can store two configs in two separate files
// FILE NAME: config-development.json:
// FILE CONTENT: {"url":"http://localhost:8000"}
// FILE NAME: config-production.json:
// FILE CONTENT: {"url":"http://google.com"}

// then load correct one and save it to variable
var config = getConfig();

function getConfig() {
  // if you pass ?dev=true to your url address default config that will be used is `config-development`
  // otherwise - `config-production`
  var configName = getParameterByName('dev', false) ? 'config-development' : 'config-production';

  window._config || (window._config = {});

  // for production version you should concat your config with main script or put it above main script
  // inside global `_config` variable for example
  if (window._config[configName]) return window._config[configName];

  // for development version you can just make an ajax call to get the config
  $.ajax({
    url : 'app/' + configName + '.json',
    async : false,
    success : function(response) {
      window._config[configName] = response;
    }
  });
  return window._config[configName];
}

// helper
function getParameterByName(name, defaults, location) {
  location = location || window.location.href;
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,'\\\[').replace(/[\]]/,'\\\]');
  var result = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(location);
  return result === null ? defaults : decodeURIComponent(result[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}

// usage
console.log(config.url); // `http://localhost:8000` for development env
                         // `http://google.` for production env
```

Comment: Thanks- that seems like a pretty good approach.  Perhaps even just manually setting an `env` variable in localStorage would work well (wouldn't have to remember to append dev=true to the URL every time).

Answer (score 3):

Another approach that I discovered is using the RequireJS configuration directly.  Since RequireJS 1.1, one can include arbitrary configuration values.  In my main configuration I set `env: 'development`' and during the build (with r.js) I set the value to `'production'`.

I created a `config` directory that contains two files: `development.js` and `production.js`.  Loading the proper file can be done with a Require plugin (we'll call it `env`):

```
define(function() {

    return {
        load: function(name, req, load, config) {
            if (!config.env || config.isBuild) {
                config.env = 'production';
            }

            var path = name + '/' + config.env;
            req([path], function(mod) {
                load(mod);
            });
        }
    };

});
```

Here's how I use it:

```
var config = require('env!config');
```